# Sequence of parentheses - Recursion in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Edit: Moving on, my code wasn't good enough - trying to change perspective

Comment: Perhaps print some debugging statements to see where it diverges?

Comment: Done that. My eye can't quite catch why, that's why i'm here :(

Comment: might be helpful or related [Generate all valid combinations of n pair of parentheses](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176856/101525)

Comment: @davewards Yeah I've seen some of it.

Comment: Trying to understand where my logic fails tho